# Spring @Transactional annotation making my class not able to Autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions

I have a class `SaveRoute` which has got an auto-wired property SaveProcessor. 
This SaveProcessor class has got a method which is annotated with @Transactional annotation. When I try to run my application, Java is throwing an exception that bean SaveProcessor dependency injection failed. When I remove `@Transactional` annotation from `SaveProcess` class method, it is working fine.

**SaveRoute**

```
public class SaveRoute implements RouteBuilder{
    @Autowired
    private SaveProcessor saveProcessor;
}
```

**SaveProcessor**

```
public class SaveProcessor implements Processor{

  @Override
  public void Process(Exchange exchange){
    this.save();
  }
  @Transactional
  public void Save(){

  }
}
```

It would be great if someone could help me on this. `@Transactional` making SaveProcessor class not a candidate for auto wiring.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to autowire on transaction class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33240700/how-to-autowire-on-transaction-class)

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context. How are you activating Spring AOP? Are you using Boot? What do your build dependencies look like?

Comment: @tsolakp's duplicate explains the problem clearly, but it's dated, so I'm not going to dupehammer this yet.

Comment: @chrylis, there were no real changes to how `Transactional` annotation works in the past 2,5 years. It's a little strange that this actually causes dependency resolution fault, admittedly. However, the answer in that is still perfectly valid.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Agreed, but the modern approach is to bypass that configuration entirely and use Boot.

Comment: @chrylis, we could just add an answer about Boot to that other one.

Answer (score 1):

agree with [Spring @Transactional annotation making my class not able to Autowire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012177/spring-transactional-annotation-making-my-class-not-able-to-autowire/48012257#48012257) answer,
it is a good practice to autowire by interface,
when you set

> @Transactional

spring make proxy of your *SaveProcessor* object,
because it implements *Processor* spring will use *DynamicProxy*.
so you don't have a bean with class *SaveProcessor* in context, you have a bean with calss *Proxy$..* wich implement intarface *Processor*.

that's why spring can't find a candidate.

it's not a problem if you have more than one implementations of *Processor*,
just use

> @Qualifier

, or autowiring by beanName. in your case

```
@Autowired
private Processor saveProcessor;
```

will be work, beacause bean has name *saveProcessor*

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Processor` interface instead of `SaveProcessor` concrete class when autowiring that kind:

```
@Autowired
private Processor saveProcessor;
```

Comment: That is not the only solution. The alternative can be to use CGLIB.

Comment: I cannot use Processor interface as Processor interface has got different implementations in my applications.

Comment: than spring's `@Qualifier` annotation should help

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out a solution. 
Adding

@Scope( proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )

on top of my SaveProcessor class resolved my issue.

I cannot use

@Autowire
public Processor SaveProcessor;

This is because there are mulpile implementation for Processor in my application.

Comment: If you are using multiple implementation then you can use `@Qualifire`. Its better if you used interface for autowiring (used interface based proxy) but if you are using class based autowiring then your class should be spring component as well. That means your class should be annotated with either `@Component` or `@Service` or `@Repository`.